# PRISM 5, StockTraderRI, NewsController: Injection magic?

Tags: unity-container, prism

In the PRISM 5 StockTrader example is a class called *NewsController*. The only usage in the application is in *ArticleNews.xaml.cs*:

```
 public partial class ArticleView : UserControl
  {
    // Note - this import is here so that the controller is created and gets wired to the     article and news reader
    // view models, which are shared instances
    [Import]
#pragma warning disable 169
    private INewsController newsController;
#pragma warning restore 169
...
}
```

I don't understand when and why an instance of *NewsController* is created.

Thx

Answer (score 0):

The PRISM 5 StockTrader uses MEF as a DI container to resolve dependencies. In this case, the NewsController class is decorated with an Export attribute.

[Export(typeof(INewsController))]

And the ArticleView has a INewsController field decorated with an Import attribute. As soon as the View is created, MEF will inject the dependency.

You might find the following articles useful:

- [Imports & Exports Attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#imports_and_exports_with_attributes)
- [Stock Trader Reference Implementation Using the Prism Library 5.0 for WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921074%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx)
- [Managing Dependencies Between Components Using the Prism Library 5.0 for WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921140%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx)

Hope this helps.

Ezequiel

http://blogs.southworks.net